# How to use popen to input and output in the same time?

Tags: c, linux, unix, pipe

I use psuedo-code to express what I want to do:

```
FILE* fd = popen("/bin/cat", ...);
Write some data to the stdin of `/bin/cat` using fd;
Read all data from the stdout of `/bin/cat` using fd;
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

popen() can only read from the new process. If you need to read and write,

- Create a pipe that will be connected to a new process using `pipe()`.
- Fork a new process using `fork()`
- redirect the process's input and outputs to the pipes that you created earlier using `dup2()`
- call exec on the child process (the new process) using `exec` family functions

Comment: Also, you need to multiplex input & output using e.g. [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) and you probably would need some [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop)